# Unwanted different line spacing

Tags: line-spacing

I'm using [Awesome-CV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) template, and I keep having different spacing for exactly the same thing. One line says *Educaction* and the other says *Experience*. Everything else is the same, but the first one has an smaller gap between lines than the second one.

I guess it is because of the *p* in *Experience*, but can't understand why so, when line spacing should be constant and unware of the letters used.

Small gap between lines:
[image: small gap]

Big gap between lines:
[image: big gap]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}

\begin{document}

\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering} % Degree
    {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)} % Institution
    {Pohang, S.Korea} % Location
    {Mar. 2010 - PRESENT} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
        \item {Got a Chun Shin-Il Scholarship which is given to promising students in CSE Dept.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {Software Engineer \& Security Researcher (Compulsory Military Service)} % Job title
    {R.O.K Cyber Command, MND} % Organization
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Aug. 2014 - Exp. Apr. 2016} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item {Implemented a military cooperation system which is web based real time messenger in Scala on Lift.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @HerrK. I thought it wasn't necessary in this case, sorry for that. Added now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a current version of `awesome-cv`.

Comment: @Johannes_B You mean you don't get the different line spacing? For the records, I compiled with `xelatex`. Nevertheless, I just downloaded the last version of `awesome-cv`, re-tried with my MWE, and still got the different line spacing. I'm starting to thing that this is a typography official rule maybe.

Comment: See comment on githu.